# How can I use Memcached to store data for a given time

Tags: php, mysql, memory, memcached

I am wondering how I would use Cache (MemCache) to display how many registered and active users I have on my website. I currently use:

```
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `active` =    1"), 0);
```

And this isn't good to use because on each page load, it's going to query the database. Which  isn't good. So how would I go upon making a "memcache" or something of that sort, where it would update that number to all users, after say 10 minutes or so?

I googled how but I couldn't really get a good how to on it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'll give you the guidelines rather than a full documentation/tutorial.

Before trying to install Memcached, you should use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysql_* functions. Checkout the warning message in [this documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

You should [install Memcached](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+install+memcached) and its [PHP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.installation.php).

Once it is done, make sure it is enabled by calling the function [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php). If Memcached isn't there the installation failed.

Here is an explicit code snippet

```
$mc = new Memcached();
$mc->addServer('localhost', 11211); // add a new server to the pool

// you will want to vary this key according to the query
// if two different queries use the same key your functions will return unexpected data
$cacheKey = 'a-custom-key-that-defines-the-data-within-it';

// how long will it take for the cache to expire in seconds : an hour
$cacheLifetime = 3600; 

$data = $mc->get($cacheKey); // we get the data from cache

// check if Memcached was able to retrieve the data
if ($mc->getResultCode() === Memcached::RES_FAILURE) {
    // if for some reasons the data is not there we get it and reinject into memcached
    $data = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `active` =    1"), 0);

    $mc->set($cacheKey, $data, $cacheLifetime); // save the data in the defined $cacheKey
}

return $data;
```